# RxJava : Using Retry with Extended Single Observable doesn't Emit the data

Tags: rx-java, observable, rx-java2

The `subscriber` doesn't receive the data if the retry operator is added to an `observable` which was created by extending `Single`.

```
    getSingle()
            .retry(1)
            .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);

    getSingleExt()
            .subscribe(res -> System.out.println("WITHOUT RETRY " + res),
                    System.out::println);

    getSingleExt()
            .retry(1)
            .subscribe(res -> System.out.println("WITH RETRY " + res),
                    System.out::println);


private static Single<String> getSingle() {
    return Single.create(emitter -> emitter.onSuccess("Single.create"));
}

private static Single<String> getSingleExt() {
    return new ExtendedSingle();
}

private static class ExtendedSingle extends Single<String> {
    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(SingleObserver<? super String> emitter) {
        emitter.onSuccess("ExtendedSingle");
    }
}
```

Output

`Single.create`

`WITHOUT RETRY ExtendedSingle`

Expected

`Single.create`

`WITHOUT RETRY ExtendedSingle`

`WITH RETRY ExtendedSingle`

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [Single](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html)?

Comment: Additional reading: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/SingleObserver.html

Comment: I went through the docs and found that with single, either result or error is dispatched once. But, using retry before subscribing gives us an option to retry `X` times, and that's exactly I'm trying to achieve. Am I failing to understand something here? Kindly guide.

Comment: Do not extend `Single` unless you understand the protocol. Use `Single.create` or the other standard factory methods.